# Is there a way to call commands in git shell on windows using Grunt.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, shell, ssh

is there a way to call Cygwin or git shell instead of CMD on Windows using Grunt.js? I'm trying to build an auto deploy system, but the ssh command in CMD does not use my RSA key with ssh. currently i'm using the grunt-shell plugin, and it works great on a mac. But because of Window's eccentricities it's not doing what I want it to do.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had a similar problem with running composer in cygwin. I overcame this by adding to my .bashrc file `script_dir=$(cygpath -w $(dirname $0))
alias composer ='php "$script_dir/composer.phar" $@'`  Which will make cygwin a little grumpy on start up but does the trick for being able to run commands like `composter update` . This doesn't solve the meat of your issue but is helpful. Grunt also talks about using cygwin and [windows a little bit here.](http://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 2):

Please try https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell

This is a good way to interact with other CLI tools. E.g. compiling Compass compass compile or get the current git branch git branch.